# ASP.Net - Get actionmethod's ParameterInfo or ParameterBindingInfo in ModelBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I implemented a custom modelbinder and override the BindModel-method with the two parameters `ControllerContext controllerContext` and `ModelBindingContext bindingContext`.

When binding I want to get the attributes of the parameters to bind:

```
public ActionResult Foo(
     [SomeAttribute("additional info for binding"))]BoundType boundParameter){
}
```

In the modelbinder I need to get the "additional info for binding".

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
   object addtionalInfoForBinding = ???

   object boundModel = ... + additionalInfoForBinding;
   return boundModel;
}
```

What I found out so far is that deep inside the `bindingContext.PropertyFilter.Target.???` there is a field/property of type `ParameterBindingInfo`. But I am not able to access this.

Is there any other "more common way" to access the parameter-attributes of the actionmethod parameters?

Comment: You could retreive that information from the PropertyDescriptor object, in that case you have to override the BindProperty method rather than BindModel.

Comment: I am going to try it. Thank you very much. I wonder, what's the difference between BindModel and BindProperty? When do I have to use one and not the other?

Comment: Depends on the requirements of your custom implementation. Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs) for further investigation.